# print elements using multi threading in bunch of 100 elements at a time for each thread

Tags: multithreading

Assume a collection containing 10000 numbers. 5 threads to be created & used, such that, at once, each thread should consume only 100 elements from the collection. After getting the 100 elements, the thread needs to print them. The threads should process the entire collection elements till end.

"ids" is the collection where i have all the 10000 elements.

I've tried as below. But first 100 elements gets skipped when i run the code again and again. Included small snippet.

```
 static int i = 0;
  static int ind = 0;
  static List<Integer> bulkIds = null;


    Runnable print = () -> {
      for (; ind <= ids.size(); ind++) {
        synchronized (Integer.valueOf(ind)) {
          synchronized (bulkIds) {
            if (ind >= ids.size()) {
              System.out.println("Data of " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + bulkIds);
              bulkIds.clear();
              return;
            }
            bulkIds.add(ids.get(ind));
            i++;
            if (i >= 100) {
              System.out.println("A Data of " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + bulkIds);
              retrievedItems.addAll(bulkIds);
              bulkIds.clear();
              i = 0;
            } else if (ind == ids.size() - 1) {
              System.out.println("B Data of " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + bulkIds);
              bulkIds.clear();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

Thread t1 = new Thread(print);
t1.setName("Thread 1");
bulkIds = new LinkedList<>();
t1.start();
Thread t2 = new Thread(print);
t2.setName("Thread 2");
bulkIds = new LinkedList<>();
t2.start();
Thread t3 = new Thread(print);
t3.setName("Thread 3");
bulkIds = new LinkedList<>();
t3.start();
Thread t4 = new Thread(print);
t4.setName("Thread 4");
bulkIds = new LinkedList<>();
t4.start();
Thread t5 = new Thread(print);
t5.setName("Thread 5");
bulkIds = new LinkedList<>();
t5.start();
```

Below is the expected output which comes correctly sometimes.

```
A Data of Thread 3 : ***[1561385, 1842204, 2045613, 2115944, 2204782, 2264358, 2282652, 2285623, 2285637, 2285642]***
A Data of Thread 3 : [2285661, 2285669, 2285669, 2288676, 2293167, 2320636, 2320636, 2493896, 2494635, 2498100]
A Data of Thread 2 : [2501421, 2502101, 2502101, 2568318, 2593569, 2621033, 2621609, 2623460, 2625041, 2684063]
A Data of Thread 1 : [2684091, 2684869, 2684869, 2688386, 2730019, 2751495, 11561385, 11842204, 12045613, 12115944]
A Data of Thread 5 : [12204782, 12264358, 12282652, 12285623, 12285637, 12285642, 12285661, 12285669, 12288676, 12293167]
A Data of Thread 1 : [12320636, 12320655, 12386260, 12493896, 12494635, 12498100, 12501421, 12502101, 12529624, 21568318]
A Data of Thread 1 : [12593569, 21621033, 21621609, 12623460, 21625041, 21684063, 26184091, 21684869, 26186133, 26818386]
A Data of Thread 1 : [27301019, 27301019, 11561385, 11842204, 12045613, 12115944, 12204782, 12264358, 12282652, 12285623]
A Data of Thread 3 : [12285637, 12285642, 12285661, 12285669, 12288676, 12293167, 12320636, 12320655, 12320655, 12386260]
A Data of Thread 3 : [12494635, 12498100, 12501421, 12502101, 12529624, 12568318, 12593569, 12621033, 12621609, 12623460]
A Data of Thread 3 : [12625041, 12684063, 12684091, 12684869, 12686133, 12688386, 12730019, 12751495, 111561385, 111842204]
A Data of Thread 2 : [112045613, 112115944, 112115944, 112264358, 112282652, 112285623, 112285637, 112285642, 112285661, 112285669]
A Data of Thread 2 : [112288676, 112293167, 112320636, 112320655, 112386260, 112493896, 112494635, 112498100, 112501421, 112502101]
A Data of Thread 2 : [112529624, 121568318, 112593569, 121621033, 121621609, 112623460, 121625041, 121684063, 126184091, 121684869]
B Data of Thread 5 : [126186133, 126818386, 126818386, 127301019]
Data of Thread 5 : []
Data of Thread 3 : []
Data of Thread 4 : []
Data of Thread 1 : []
Data of Thread 2 : []
```

Below output appears mostly, where above output should come. (1st line data is skipped somehow - in above output we can see)

```
A Data of Thread 3 : []
A Data of Thread 1 : [2285661, 2285669, 2288676, 2293167, 2293167, 2320636, 2386260, 2493896, 2494635, 2498100]
A Data of Thread 1 : [2501421, 2502101, 2529624, 2568318, 2593569, 2621033, 2621609, 2623460, 2625041, 2684063]
A Data of Thread 1 : [2684091, 2684869, 2686133, 2688386, 2730019, 2751495, 11561385, 11842204, 12045613, 12115944]
A Data of Thread 1 : [12204782, 12264358, 12282652, 12285623, 12285637, 12285642, 12285661, 12285669, 12288676, 12293167]
A Data of Thread 4 : [12320636, 12320655, 12386260, 12493896, 12494635, 12498100, 12501421, 12502101, 12529624, 21568318]
A Data of Thread 5 : [12593569, 21621033, 21621609, 12623460, 21625041, 21684063, 26184091, 21684869, 26186133, 26818386]
A Data of Thread 5 : [27301019, 27514195, 11561385, 11842204, 12045613, 12115944, 12204782, 12264358, 12282652, 12285623]
A Data of Thread 5 : [12285637, 12285642, 12285661, 12285669, 12288676, 12293167, 12320636, 12320655, 12386260, 12493896]
A Data of Thread 5 : [12494635, 12498100, 12501421, 12502101, 12529624, 12568318, 12593569, 12621033, 12621609, 12621609]
A Data of Thread 5 : [12625041, 12684063, 12684091, 12684869, 12686133, 12688386, 12730019, 12751495, 111561385, 111842204]
A Data of Thread 5 : [112045613, 112115944, 112204782, 112264358, 112282652, 112285623, 112285637, 112285642, 112285661, 112285669]
A Data of Thread 5 : [112288676, 112293167, 112320636, 112320655, 112386260, 112493896, 112494635, 112498100, 112501421, 112502101]
A Data of Thread 5 : [112529624, 121568318, 112593569, 121621033, 121621609, 112623460, 121625041, 121684063, 126184091, 121684869]
B Data of Thread 5 : [126186133, 126818386, 127301019, 127514195]
Data of Thread 5 : []
Data of Thread 2 : []
Data of Thread 3 : []
Data of Thread 4 : []
Data of Thread 1 : []
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You want us to solve your problems, while you doing nothing?

Comment: Missed to include what i tried. Updated now.

Comment: Ravindra Ranwala ---- You said "What have you tried so far? You want us to solve your problems, while you doing nothing?". Could you tell us the solution if you know.

Comment: Currently I am bit busy. But I'll definitely check this out when I am free. Anyway I am glad that you have tried something before posting.